# Is there a way to use a selenium webdriver without showing the browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I tried searching for a solution on this site because there is a question that is almost the same as mine. This sadly this didn't work for me. The code below is what I have right now... Is it possible to start the webdriver without actually showing the process?

```
# Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')


# Gegevens
password = input("Please give us a password you want to use for all your account(s): ")


# Start de driver
url = 'https://twitter.com/?lang=en-gb'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1600, 800)
driver.get(url)
```

Edit:
I fixed it by replacing with the code in the answer:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

I still get an error:

```
C:/Users/ducov/PycharmProjects/bot/app.py:18: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

But I don't think that matters

Comment: Where are you stuck? What error do you see?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) this is the line where the error starts:

Comment: The error is really long, DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) may be helpfull? FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ducov/PycharmProjects/bot/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options),

Comment: Update the main question with all these information.

Comment: There you go, I updated it.

Comment: Why call `webdriver.Chrome()` twice? Just use `driver = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_driver", options=options)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close enough.

First of all, `chrome_options` is deprecated now and you have to use `options`instead.

- [Implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.html#WebDriver):

  ```
  if chrome_options:
      warnings.warn('use options instead of chrome_options', DeprecationWarning)
      options = chrome_options
  ```

Second, you want to initialize a single *Chrome* browsing context only, so you need to pass both the arguments within a single *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* initializer as follows:

```
# Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

# Gegevens
password = input("Please give us a password you want to use for all your account(s): ")

# Start de driver
url = 'https://twitter.com/?lang=en-gb'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1600, 800)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Thank you, my program now works completely without bugs.

Comment: Of course! Could you maybe take a look at my other question I just posted? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You should put `execute_path` and `chrome_options` in same line.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

ps: in your code, you run 2 Chrome instances, one is `webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver')`, and another is `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`

Comment: Thanks, I think this works but now I get this error: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ducov/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options). Does this actually matter?

Comment: It means selenium will replace parameter `chrome_options` to `options` in a future version, you can replace it to `options` to avoid this warning.